# Require Once Failing Relative Path

Tags: php

I have the following file structure in my project:

```
+ server
  + api
    + product
      - get.php
  + database
    - product.php
  + model
    - product.php
  + service
    - product.php
  + utilities
    - controller.php
    - database.php
```

Then in my `server/api/product/get.php` I have the following lines:

```php
require_once("../../service/product.php");
require_once("../../utilities/controller.php");
```

I believe this is properly loading the service because when I use Insomnia to hit the endpoint I am getting this error in the `server/api/service/product.php` file:

> Warning: require_once(../model/product.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in C:\full path removed\server\service\product.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '../model/product.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

In my `server/service/product.php` file I have the following:

```php
require_once("../model/product.php");
require_once("../database/product.php");
```

And it is failing on the first `require_once`.

So my question to y'all is why would the relative path in my controller layer work, but the relative path in the service layer fail?

Comment: `require` changes the current path, for any "successive" requires after/inside that script that gets called using "require" again. I believe. You could try absolute paths. There is a php global that derives the absolute, but i am unsure of its name at the moment. Im going to upvote in hopes to bring more attention

Comment: Did you mean `__DIR__` [magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)? @GetSet

Comment: @Remy - based on your suggestion, I was able to get it to work using relative paths by prefixing the path in `require_once` with the `__DIR__` magic constant. If you want to post an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could as an alternative use the `__DIR__` [magic constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) as per the documentation the constant gives: 'The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned'. Which reduces the likelihood of errors through relative pathing.

Example:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../service/product.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use include and require never without __DIR__. A relative path that starts with. or .. has the current directory as a base. The current working directory depends on various settings. __DIR__ is always the directory where the file itself is located.

For include the
server/service/product.php
from the file
server/api/product/get.php
you can do this:

```
require_once __DIR__."/../../service/product.php";
```